Xcode 16 iOS 18 compilation error with flutter integrated
App I am working on is native iOS app with flutter project integrated through cocoa pods. Day before when iOS 18 officially released, had to update to Xcode 16 and iOS 18. while I tried to compile the code I am getting this error which I am not able to get source of it. Can anyone pls guide me fixing this issue.pasting more
1.  Apple Swift version 6.0 (swiftlang-6.0.0.9.10 clang-1600.0.26.2)
2.  Compiling with effective version 5.10
Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
0  swift-frontend           0x000000010d3d8088 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) + 40
1  swift-frontend           0x000000010d3d5e59 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 233
2  swift-frontend           0x000000010d3d8646 SignalHandler(int) + 278
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ff8036e9e9d _sigtramp + 29
4  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ff7b90a7b20 _sigtramp + 18446744072461474976
5  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007ff8035d5b19 abort + 126
6  swift-frontend           0x00000001075bb49a swift::DiagnosticHelper::Implementation::diagnoseFatalError(char const*, bool) + 762
7  swift-frontend           0x000000010d33be72 llvm::report_fatal_error(llvm::Twine const&, bool) + 402
8  swift-frontend           0x000000010d33bcd9 llvm::report_fatal_error(char const*, bool) + 41
9  swift-frontend           0x000000010783cf25 llvm::detail::PassModel<llvm::Module, llvm::VerifierPass, llvm::PreservedAnalyses, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module>>::run(llvm::Module&, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module>&) + 165
10 swift-frontend           0x000000010d0da025 llvm::PassManager<llvm::Module, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module>>::run(llvm::Module&, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module>&) + 245
11 swift-frontend           0x000000010782e7e7 swift::performLLVMOptimizations(swift::IRGenOptions const&, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*, llvm::raw_pwrite_stream*) + 4039
12 swift-frontend           0x0000000107830645 swift::performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::DiagnosticEngine&, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, llvm::GlobalVariable*, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::vfs::OutputBackend&, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 2149
13 swift-frontend           0x00000001071b5929 generateCode(swift::CompilerInstance&, llvm::StringRef, llvm::Module*, llvm::GlobalVariable*) + 361
14 swift-frontend           0x00000001071afb88 performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule>>, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 2568
15 swift-frontend           0x00000001071ae696 swift::performCompileStepsPostSema(swift::CompilerInstance&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 1094
16 swift-frontend           0x00000001071b2e1b performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 4651
17 swift-frontend           0x00000001071b0d58 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 4392
18 swift-frontend           0x00000001071236a7 swift::mainEntry(int, char const**) + 8103
19 dyld                     0x00007ff8033272cd start + 1805


Show me error i have done my update and solved the all error in some hours.

@YasirAli updated screenshot

Add To this steps  you need to update Firebase CLI

My team and I discovered this issue with relation to the Firebase packages. This approach may or may not solve your issue.
For now, the recommended fix is to change the Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules setting in Xcode to Yes. There is an issue open that we can monitor for a real fix in Firebase packages

It didn't work for me though :(

Sorry it did not work for you. I do not understand why my answer was downvoted, it worked in our project. Without additional information it is hard to provide a specific answer.
