Flutter error while running iOS Simulator
I'm trying to run the app on iOS Simualator and I get a long error I cannot share here.
I cannot find anything online that could help me. I updated everything on pubspec, and tried to disable those libraries as well.
Nobody had this problem before and I don't know what to search for.
ChatGPT synthesised it for me:


Not sure if this is your issue but there have been issues with Xcode 16, I proposed an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79002652/xcode-16-ios-18-compilation-error-with-flutter-integrated/79003761#79003761.
