Flutter Xcode 16: Not able to run the app only build work
After updating to Xcode 16 I'm facing an issue with running the app on the simulator and also on a real device.
FYI: Xcode 15.4 works fine I have tried that on a different Mac because the current one after updating to MacOS 15 Xcode 15.4 not supported anymore.
Error log:
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _XPluginsGetDataFuncOrAbort

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _XPluginsGetFunctionPtrFromID

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: Plugins::SocketThreadLocalScope::SocketThreadLocalScope(int)

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: Plugins::SocketThreadLocalScope::~SocketThreadLocalScope()

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 16 Pro Max.

Flutter Doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 15.0 24A335 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-AE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.2.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.93.1)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

  # firebase
  firebase_core: ^3.6.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^4.1.3
  firebase_messaging: ^15.1.3
  firebase_analytics: ^11.3.3
  firebase_instance_id: ^1.1.0

enter image description here
I have updated all Firebase libraries to the latest version and changed the value of Allow Non-Modular Includes In Framework Modules to YES After all those steps I cleared the builds and pods and re-install the pods and packages and I am still facing same error.
UPDATE: I finally found where is the issue. It is because of the facebook_app_events package, and the cause of it is FBAudienceNetwork in pods has some problems with Linker with CPP while the version of it is the last is FBAudienceNetwork: 6.15.2 and for facebook_app_events: ^0.19.3.
I just removed this package for now, and all works fine, Please if anyone has suggestions do let me know.
UPDATE 2: Solved after back to the version facebook_app_events: ^0.18.3

You could check out the answer I gave on this post, it may or may not be the answer you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79002652/xcode-16-ios-18-compilation-error-with-flutter-integrated/79003761#79003761

Hello @ChillBroDev, Actually, I have tried this solution, but it didn't work for me I set the setting like the screenshot in the post, Do you have any other suggestions?

Hello @Abood Helani, my apologies for missing the screenshot. Generally that has been working for people. Another thing you could try is to remove the Pods folder then run "pod install --repo-update" this will update the repos where pods pulls in the iOS binaries. Generally this works for me when having pod issues. My team and I updated to Xcode 16 and only had the "YES" issue. There could be another Pod causing issues. It's hard to tell.

Hello @ChillBroDev, Sorry it was my fault I didn't set the image properly, so I have also done pod install -repo-update and am still facing the same issue,
